# Java 8 comparingInt with null values

Tags: java, int, compare, java-stream, comparator

I have a functionality to sort a list of pojo by 3 Integer fields.

Currently I am using `comparingInt()` and `thenComparingBy()`.

But i may get a null value in between. This throws a `NullPointerException`.

For this i want to add null values at the end. `Comparator.nullsLast()` does not work for my case as I am comparing by 3 integer values.

Is there a way to achieve this....

Comment: So you have `Integer` fields, not `int` fields, right? Otherwise they could not be `null`, or is the entire object containing the fields `null`?

Comment: Yeah Integer fields

Comment: You will have to implement your own comparator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your component `Integer` objects are `null` you cannot use `comparingInt` with them. Instead of using `comparingInt`, first create a helper null-safe Integer comparator, and use that in your Pojo comparator.

```
Comparator<Integer> nullsLast = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());
Comparator<Pojo> pojoComparator = Comparator.comparing(Pojo::getFirstInteger, nullsLast)
            .thenComparing(Pojo::getSecondInteger, nullsLast)
            .thenComparing(Pojo::getThirdInteger, nullsLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way seems to be to write a comparator that's specific to the exact concerns that apply to sorting the particular pojo.

It seems to me more obvious than duct-taping parts together that don't behave how you want them (e.g., comparingInt not tolerating null references).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already three years old, but why you don't just adapt the key extractor for `Comparing.comparingInt`?

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(4, 2, 7, 3, null, 1, 9)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Objects.nonNull(i) ? i : Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

In my example i have an Int-Stream with a null value. To catch and adapt it for the comparator you just have to check it in the key extractor. If the integer is null you change it to another value. Here i took Integer.MAX_VALUE to put the element to the end of the list.